# How to run function in another vue.file from their imported file

Tags: vue.js

I'm new with vue.js, I have two different vue files:

This is the first file:

```
import second from second.vue;
export default{
  component: {second},
  data() {return{
    data: 'data',
  }}
  methods: {
    function f1{
      console.log(this.data);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.f1;
  }
}
```

This is the second file :

```
export default{
name: 'second',
  props: {item:Object},
  methods: {
    function f2{
      // here is the function i need to restart f1.
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.f1;
  }
}
```

I want to rerun the f1 function from vue file when the f2 function is run. How can I trigger the function in the first file from the imported file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom event
on f2 function

```
f2(){this.$emit('myEvent')}
```

Then listen to the event and fire the f1 function

```
<second-component v-on:myEvent="f1"></second-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, dont forget the name in any component.

To communicate between components, you can use props (parent to children) or events (children to parent). See the doc here:

- Props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html
- Events: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Basically, to communicate from children to parent:

Children:

```js
  mounted() {
    var returnObj = { name: 'John', id: 1241 }; 
    this.$emit("emitToParentEvent", returnObj);
  }
```

And in parent (first declare the component and last, in methods, add event):

```js
<children-name @emitToParentEvent="emitToParentEvent"></children-name>



-------
  methods: {

    emitToParentEvent(returnObj){
      //access my returnObj
    }
  }
```